Can i use view engine in SvelteKit?
I'm using SvelteKit and NodeJS(as web server). And I want to use view engine so I set
<!-- +page.svelte -->
<template lang="pug">
...
</template>

Then I'm trying to set
// server.ts 
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index')
})

But I don't know Where should I set the  pug file path.
How can I do that?
I want to make both SvelteKit page is
rendered and Node server is also running when only the Node server is running.

I think that's possible, but I've never tried it myself, so can't say anything about it by Good Luck! :)
